# MyBatis SDO_NN inject parameter exception

Tags: java, java-8, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-sql

I am using MyBatis with Java 8. I am trying to inject mybatis parameters into SDO_NN constructor in oracle like;

```
SELECT 
            
            c.COLUMNNAME_ID as columnId,
            TRIM(c.COLUMNNAME_NAME) as columnName,
            c.COLUMNNAME_OWNER_ID as columnOwnerId , 
            c.LATITUDE as latitude,
            c.LONGITUDE as longitude,
            TRIM(c.ADDRESS) as address,
            TRIM(c.CITY) as city,
            TRIM(c.DISTRICT) as district,
            TRIM(c.PHONE_NUMBER) as phoneNumber,
            TRUNC(SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1),3)  distance
        FROM TABLE_NAME c
        WHERE c.COLUMNNAME_STATUS = 'ACT'
            AND c.COLUMNAME_OWNER_ID = 'XXX'
            AND SDO_NN(c.XY, sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(#{queryInput.longitude},#{queryInput.latitude},NULL), NULL,  NULL),
                'SDO_NUM_RES=5000 distance=#{queryInput.radius} unit=m', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

But it gives me the exception below.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
### The error may exist in com/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/mapper/CustomMapperOracle.xml
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT  c.COLUMNNAME_ID as columnId,    TRIM(c.COLUMNNAME_NAME) as columnName,    c.COLUMNNAME_OWNER_ID as columnOwnerId,     c.LATITUDE as latitude,    c.LONGITUDE as longitude,    c.MCC_NUM as mccNum,    c.BRAND_NUM as brandNum,    TRIM(c.ADDRESS) as address,    TRIM(c.CITY) as city,    TRIM(c.DISTRICT) as district,    TRIM(c.PHONE_NUMBER) as phoneNumber,    TRUNC(SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1),3)  distance   FROM TABLE_NAME c   WHERE c.COLUMNNAME_STATUS = 'A'    AND c.COLUMNAME_OWNER_ID = 'XXX'    AND SDO_NN(c.XY, sdo_geometry(2001, 8307,          sdo_point_type(?,?,NULL), NULL,  NULL),          'SDO_NUM_RES=? distance=? unit=m', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

When I changed code to this one;

```
 SELECT 
            
            c.COLUMNNAME_ID as columnId,
            TRIM(c.COLUMNNAME_NAME) as columnName,
            c.COLUMNNAME_OWNER_ID as columnOwnerId , 
            c.LATITUDE as latitude,
            c.LONGITUDE as longitude,
            TRIM(c.ADDRESS) as address,
            TRIM(c.CITY) as city,
            TRIM(c.DISTRICT) as district,
            TRIM(c.PHONE_NUMBER) as phoneNumber,
            TRUNC(SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1),3)  distance
        FROM TABLE_NAME c
        WHERE c.COLUMNNAME_STATUS = 'ACT'
            AND c.COLUMNAME_OWNER_ID = 'XXX'
            AND SDO_NN(c.XY, sdo_geometry(2001, 8307, sdo_point_type(#{queryInput.longitude},#{queryInput.latitude},NULL), NULL,  NULL),
                'SDO_NUM_RES=5000 distance=10000 unit=m', 1) = 'TRUE'
```

It works, I am trying to parameterized the distance.

The only change between first query and second query is

from

> distance=#{queryInput.radius}

to

> 10000

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `#{}` is a placeholder (i.e. `?` in `java.sql.PreparedStatement`), so you cannot use it in a literal. You have to either 1) pass the entire literal as a parameter or 2) use `${}` instead (i.e. `'SDO_NUM_RES=5000 distance=${queryInput.radius} unit=m'`). If you chose 2) and `queryInput.radius` is a string, do not use user entered value without sanitizing it to avoid SQL injection. See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for more info.